# How to read a text from DB which has anchor tag embedded into it and display the same in mvc & C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have  a row in DB which contains a text which looks like the below

```
Will candidate handle Personally Identifiable Information (PII) as defined <a target ='_blank' href='http://intranet.hp.com/sites/privacyrulebook/Pages/Glossary.aspx'> here</a>?
```

i will read the same in asp.net MVC, C# and the same will be printed on the page.

MY requirement is the text should be displayed as a text and with an link which is also mentioned in the text. Please have a look at the anchor tag in the above DB Text.

some one please help

Comment: Also whats your actual question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want "`here`" to be a link, you can do this:

`@(new HtmlString(Model.TheTextFromDB))`

Where `Model.TextFromDB` is your actual text. This will print your text and make "`here`" a link. If this is some arbitrary text that someone else put in there, you might not want to just show that without filtering it first.

Comment: Thanks a lot Filip Ekberg. You saved my time :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use

```
<%= model.HtmlContent %>
```

or

```
@Html.Raw(model.Content)
```